# Angular 6: how do I add a JSON string to an existing JSON string-array?

Tags: arrays, json, angular, typescript, angular6

So I have a Typescript component with a constructor that looks like this:

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.http.get('/api/values/users').subscribe(result => {
      this.values = result as string[];
    }, error => console.error(error));
  }
```

and as you can see it makes a string array and stores it in values. I later display this string[] in the html with something like this snippet

```
<tr *ngFor="let value of values; index as i">
      <td>
        <input [(ngModel)]="value.id" class="form-control" type="text" name="{{value.id}}" />
      </td>
</tr>
```

the problem is I later want to add a new element to the string array in JSON format. But when I write

```
this.values.push("{id: 1, username: , firstName: , lastName: , token: ,}");
```

It doesn't match the JSON format and so the string becomes:

```
0: {id: 2, name: "provider", password: "gps", roles: 4, status: 1}
1: {id: 4, name: "Josh", password: "pass", roles: 1, status: 1}
2: {id: 5, name: "admin", password: "admin", roles: 1, status: 1}
3: "{id: 1, username: , firstName: , lastName: , token: ,}"
```

notice the last value has double qoutes around it. This makes it so that the *ngFor that was aformentioned does not pick up on it as a JSON format and just thinks the fourth object here is just a regular string. 
Please help me!

Comment: The `values` member is not a `string` array, is a `{id:number,name:string,password:string, roles:number,status:number}` array. The fact that you cast it to string has no effect on the deserialized form of your objects. This is why you cant simply push a string into your array.

Comment: *"just thinks the fourth object here is just a regular string"* - ...because it **is** just a regular string, that's what you put in the array.

Answer (score 0):

The string `JSON` format missing quotes. 
Try below syntax  :

```
this.values.push(JSON.parse('{"id": "1", "username": null, 
"firstName": null, "lastName": null, "token": ","}'))
```

Answer (score 0):

you must do the Object.assign(). This is an EXAMPLE that merges your returned values object with your new object that has a new element on it.

```
this.values= Object.assign({},this.values,{newElementFieldName: this.newObject});
```